# Android refreshing text values of radio button depending on size of ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, onclick, radio-button

I have 2 `ArrayList<String>` : one for the questions (size 6) and one for the related answers (4 answers for each questions). I would like to manage these behind an `onClick()` method. So: when i click on a button i want to refresh anytime all the values inside of:
a `ListView` (the adapter is filled with the `arraylist` of questions).
RadioButtons (every button should appear with the related answers for the question given in the listView adapter). For the questions i'm using a simple subList(); infact for the first question i search for the value starting from 0 to 1. The next question starting from 1,2 etc... . For the answers i'm refreshing the textvalues with this: `radio1.setText("arraylistquestions".get(0));`
`radio2.setText("arraylistquestions".get(1));` etc.. 
I'm sure this is not the best way cos it is too much static. I think i need something more efficient. Do you have any ideas? Hope you got my english. Sorry. Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0):

I might not get the question right. If by refreshing you mean new data for item views for the answers then you should feed your `Cursor` with new data (the array list that contains the next round of Q&A) and in `getView()` do the `setText(babla.get(0))` etc...so you do this ONLY once. and then call (where you think next round should start) `cursor.notifyDatasetChanged();` to apply the new data to the listview. There for, you dont have to do manually `setText()`, now the `getView()`does that for you everytime you call `.notifyDatasetChanged();`. I hope this gave you general idea how stuff work.

Comment: Hi Nikola. Thanks a lot for your answer. But i didn't get what are you tryin' to tell me. Refreshing is about clicking a button so declare onClick() method and inside that put my ListView with the question title and refreshing it every time i click on that button. Do the same for the radiobutton text values. Now you get it? Thanks man.

Comment: Yes, I got. My brain tells me exactly the same I said. You override the onClick() so when you click you feed the cursor with data, call nDChngd() you populate the listview. Tada! We gave the listview (This applies for everytime that button is clicked). But you do the setText() in getView()...

Comment: I have no cursor. I have only some conditions like: if(radio1.isChecked() == true)
             {
               risp=risposte.get(0);
               
               ls1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 strings2.subList(1, 2)));
               ls1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);               
             }

and doing that i know that it is not correct. What about the cursor you are talking about?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 watch this video of Romain Guy and do some reading about cursors http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

As long as it works it is correct, striving for better solution is another thing...Read and watch this you'll see what i'm talking about.

Comment: Pretty good video. But i don't think that we have focused my problem. With getView() i have to put always my setText(blabla.get(0)). And i don't want this. I want to iterate my arrayList without giving every time that method. So i think that i need a kind of method which iterates my arrayList (maybe a for) but i don't know how. Here i put my code so maybe you can understand much more. Thanks a lot. http://pastebin.com/8gk12vrR